# How to create Pandas Dataframe using the lists of the vairable length as rows?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to create a Pandas Dataframe using the number of lists as rows, the issue I'm facing is the length of the lists are not same. I already know there would be columns like this in the DataFrame:

```
  col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
 ------|-------|------|------|------
       |       |      |      |
       |       |      |      |
```

Now if a list length is less than 5, say 3 then I want that only the first 3 columns will get filled with the list elements and the remaining ones should get the values as null or N/A.

Comment: Can yo uadd some example of list? It is only one? Or list of lists?

Comment: I have a number of lists that I'm getting by processing some raw data.

Comment: So nested lists? There are same lengths?

Comment: Not nested lists just creating the lists one by one out the processed data. Each time getting a list (just a plain one with the simple primitive type) want to add it as a new row.

Comment: DataFrame is empty before appending?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need if `L` are nested lists and is possible variable lengths:

```
maxL = max(L, key=len)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=df.columns[:len(maxL)]).reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

But if want append in time, what is not effective:

```
for val in L:
    df = df.append(dict(zip(df.columns[:len(val)], val)), ignore_index=True)
```